# How do I prevent X11 opening an xterm when it starts?

Tags: x11

When I start the X11.app then it launches an xterm automatically.  I've long since switched from the "ordinary" xterm to rxvt-unicode so the initial xterm just hangs around like a wallflower never being used.  Whilst it's not particularly *bad*, it spoils the look of the place so I'd like to stop it launching.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
defaults write org.xquartz.X11 app_to_run /usr/bin/true
```

in a Terminal. However, note that it normally shouldn't be necessary to ever start XQuartz.app (or X11.app; see the comments) manually. It will start automatically when you run an X11 client, and then it will not start its defaults startup application.

Comment: Uh, sorry, I hadn't noticed that you use X11.app. Don't do that. Use [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) for all your X11 needs on the mac. That said, I think X11.app has the same defaults setting, but I don't remember the name of the preferences file. Look for it in Library/Preferences/.

Comment: Last time I used Mac OS X then XQuartz wasn't around so I hadn't heard of that - any other things like that I should know about?  For X11 it's `org.x.X11`, and I set the value to `''` which seemed to work as well as `/usr/bin/true`.

Comment: Hmm. No, I can't think of anything other than X11/XQuartz with that particular peculiarity. Though I remain forever confused about whether I should get my Java updates from Apple or Oracle these days.

Comment: if you use fink, packages are not built for Xquartz on 10.6. so your suggestion is invalid, harald.

Comment: @Wyatt8740 I'll take your word for it. I don't have any suggestions for what to do in that case. If you do find out, feel free to add your own answer or comment. (Or if you need the answer but don't know how, ask a new question.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I have the answer, but the truth is that some people don't have the choice to use quartz :(

Comment: So is there still some kind of .xinitrc or xinit application?  I'm bugged by the foxtrotting xterm but it's easy to imagine a situation in which I'd want to run multiple 'something elses.'  Should I defaults write ~/myxinitrc.sh or is XQuartz still looking for a fixed file name?

Comment: @AndrewWolfe I am getting a bit rusty here, so take this with a grain of salt. XQuartz will run `xinit` on startup. And that runs the shell script `/usr/X11/lib/X11/xinit/xinitrc`, which in turn runs scripts in `/usr/X11/lib/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/`. In there, you find `98-user.sh`, which will run all executable shell scripts in `~/.xinitrc.d/` with names ending in `.sh`. Note that you can short circuit this by having one of the latter shell scripts `exec` your desired window manager. Then the default `xterm` is not run.

Comment: … and all of that (previous comment) means that I am not sure my answer, now almost five years old, is still valid.

Answer (score 6):

Since I'm not at my OSX computer right now, I'll give you the fail-proof answer for this. 'true' does nothing and exits successfully, so I set that to run at startup.

Apple's old X11:
`defaults write org.x.X11 app_to_run $(which true)`

and for XQuartz:
`defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 app_to_run $(which true)`

and for MacPorts X11.app:
`defaults write org.macports.X11 app_to_run $(which true)`

In case you are wondering, `$(which true)` will make a line read, for example,
`defaults write org.x.X11 app_to_run /bin/true`.
I write it as `$(which true)` because I am not at my mac and do not remember if it is in /bin/true or some other location.

I have additionally read that you can set these to `''` (that's two single quotes, so nothing at all), and it will do the same thing. I have not tried it, though.

(Source: https://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X11-UsersFAQ)

(edited because I forgot the all important 'app_to_run' in my examples)

Comment: Yes, the `''` worked for me on Big Sur with zsh shell instead of true (as true is builtin for zsh).

Comment: @Christian Oh, did Big Sur replace bash/bourne shell with zsh and remove `/bin/true`? I had no idea (my mac won't run Big Sur).

Answer (score 6):

It appears that starting with XQuartz 2.8 you would do:

```
defaults write org.xquartz.X11 app_to_run APP
```

Comment: This would be better as an edit to the other answers https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/183267/237 looks the most complete

Comment: This worked on Xquartz 2.8.1, Mac OS Catalina (accepted answer didn't).