# XQuartz setting default shell for xterm under Ventura

Tags: terminal, command-line, zsh, login-items, xquartz

In a clean rebuild of Ventura, my default shell is `/bin/zsh`.  For instance, that is what shows up in a Terminal.app terminal.  If I start an xterm (launched from XQuartz 2.8.4), the shell shown in `$SHELL` is `/bin/sh` (& in other tests, see Comments).  The xterm should be using my default shell, but can't seem to make that happen.

I did notice that `defaults read org.xquartz.X11 login_shell` shows `/bin/sh`.  However, I changed that to zsh with a `defaults write`, restarted the computer, and there was no change in behavior.

Edit, more info:
Setting the XQuartz app_to_run parameter to `xmessage $0` reports `-zsh`, but setting app_to_run to `xterm` produces an xterm running `sh`.  I'm so confused.

Edit, even more info:
I've pushed the problem back to the XQuartz starting context.  The problem only occurs if XQuartz is started as a Login item, or if it is started with a launcher (I use Quicksilver) which itself was a Login item.  So it appears that Mac Login items are not using the default shell.  Can anyone else replicate?

Comment: `$SHELL` may be set to `/bin/sh`, but what shell is actually running?  `$SHELL` is just an environment variable, it doesn't *control* anything.  XQuartz would seem to be seriously broken if it were not starting the user's login shell by default.

Comment: @MarcWilson Both `ps -p $$` and `echo $0` report `-sh`.   I added an `echo` line to `.zshrc`, and it does not print out in an xterm started by XQuartz.  An xterm started through a command in Terminal (and running under XQuartz) have the zsh shell (according to all of these tests).

Comment: From _man xterm_ : _Normally xterm checks the SHELL variable. If that is not set, xterm tries to use the shell program specified in the password file. If that is not set, xterm uses /bin/sh._ So I would first check the /etc/passwd, then check `SHELL` using `printenv SHELL` **inside the shell opened by `xterm`**, to verify that the variable is in the environment.

Comment: Aside from this: I don't know XQuartz, but instead of researching what's going on here, can't you set `app_to_run` explicitly to `xterm /bin/zsh -l` instead of just `xterm`?

Comment: @user1934428: The header of /etc/passwd says, "this file is consulted directly only when the system is running in single-user mode" and that otherwise Open Directory is used.  Is that policy overridden by xterm?  macOS does not normally have any real users in /etc/passwd.

Comment: @user1934428: `app_to_run` is what XQuartz will run when XQuartz is launched.  Since one may have a variety of X11 apps, I (and I think many users) do not want an xterm to run when XQuartz is launched. (e.g. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53734/how-do-i-prevent-x11-opening-an-xterm-when-it-starts )

Comment: @James6M : I don't know whether the `xterm` port for xquartz also adhered to this convention; probably it doesn't. Therefore my suggestion stands that you supply the shell explicitly instead of having xterm figuring it out automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I did two things. Neither one worked until I restarted the computer, so I am not sure which method was the effective one:

1. In **Terminal** / Settings / Shells open with: I put `/bin/tcsh`
2. In **System Settings** / Users & Groups, I right-clicked on my username to get an "Advanced Options..." dialog. The dialog has an area where I selected `/bin/tcsh` for my login shell from a dropdown menu.

Again, neither of these worked in the new X11 `xterm` until I restarted the computer. If anyone has more info on the differences between these two methods, please feel free to edit this response.

I know the original question was how to get `/bin/sh`, but since `sh` and `tcsh` are both available, I assume the same method will work for any available shell you want.

Comment: I find it confusing that in your question, you complained that your terminal would not run **zsh**, and in the answer you propose here, you configure the terminal to run **tcsh**. Of course you can configure each Terminal tab to launch any shell of your liking, but why now the switch from a modern zsh to the hopelessly outdated tcsh?

Comment: Note that this post is not from the OP (me).  I gather that @giardia was having the same problem, just with a different desired shell.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of the described changes fixed things for me.  Six months on, it remains true that [Login Item> XQuartz> xterm] or [Login Item> Quicksilver> XQuartz> xterm] launch with sh, but call histories that don't start with Login Items launch with zsh.  My work-around has been to put /bin/zsh explicitly in the xterm command.