# How to let XQuartz opens a startup window when you start it?

Tags: x11

Earlier, some one asked, "How do I prevent X11 opening an xterm when it starts?", and Jay provided the answer "defaults write org.xquartz.X11 app_to_run APP", and it works.

I did that and now I would like to undo, or negate, its effect. What should I do?

Comment: For greater context, could you [edit] and add the link to the other question?

Comment: Generally speaking, you can remove changes by executing the command `defaults delete <Property>`

Comment: Just to confirm, do you mean [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/421444/119271) by Jay?

Comment: Jay's answer is "defaults write org.xquartz.X11 app_to_run APP".

Comment: Try running this command: `defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 nolisten_tcp -boolean YES; defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 app_to_run '' && defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 app_to_run /usr/bin/xterm; defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 app_is_trusted -boolean YES; defaults write org.x.X11 wm_ffm -bool true; killall X11`. It basically sets XQuartz to open an `xterm` window as the startup window. Does that work for you?